# Automate google login and download app statistic

Tags: java, google-play, htmlunit

So currently i have a scraping program that logs into a google account and grab application data from google play developer console (downloads, ANR, crashes, etc.). I use java and HTMLUnit library for the scraper. Here is a snippet for the login part:

```
public static void login(String url)
{
  try
  {
    Utility.turn_off_warning(webclient); //this is just to turn off the warning in HTMLUnit

    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webclient.getPage(url);
    //getting the elements
    HtmlTextInput email = (HtmlTextInput)page.getElementById("Email"); 
    HtmlPasswordInput pass = (HtmlPasswordInput)page.getElementById("Passwd");
    HtmlSubmitInput submit = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.getElementById("signIn");

// inserting value

    email.setValueAttribute(Settings.google_username);
    pass.setValueAttribute(Settings.google_pass);

// press login button
    HtmlPage afterLogin = (HtmlPage)submit.click();


    System.out.print("Logged In");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

so the code above works for the login part, until google changed the structure for the login page just few weeks ago IIRC, in which now you have to input the email first, press the next button, input the password, then press the sign-in button. I tried to set my scraper to do exactly that, but it didn't work. I guess that it's because any changes from the javascript in the page can't be processed by HTMLUnit, so now I'm stuck. Any help or suggestion are much appreciated... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution.

```
 webclient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

i added this line, and it works. i only need to change the flow from

```
grabbing all elements -> set all value -> click submit
```

to

```
grab email input and submit button -> set email -> 
submit -> grab password and submit button -> set password -> submit
```